# How to fix Error when checking target: expected activation_5 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (24943, 50, 50, 1)

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm constructing a CNN to predict cats and dogs from kaggle (filetype: jpg). I use a tensorflow backend in an anaconda environment with Python 3.6. But I get this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_8 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (24943, 50, 50, 1)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)
pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb"`
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)
X = X/255.0
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) 
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.3)
```

Here's the model.summary() table

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d_22 (Conv2D)           (None, 48, 48, 256)       2560

---

activation_30 (Activation)   (None, 48, 48, 256)       0

---

max_pooling2d_22 (MaxPooling (None, 24, 24, 256)       0

---

conv2d_23 (Conv2D)           (None, 22, 22, 256)       590080

---

activation_31 (Activation)   (None, 22, 22, 256)       0

---

max_pooling2d_23 (MaxPooling (None, 11, 11, 256)       0

---

flatten_11 (Flatten)         (None, 30976)             0

---

dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 64)                1982528

---

dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 65

---

## activation_32 (Activation)   (None, 1)                 0

Total params: 2,575,233
Trainable params: 2,575,233
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Comment: What are the shapes of X and y.?

Comment: the shape of X and y are (24943, 50, 50, 1)

Comment: Both X and y are (24943, 50, 50, 1) .?

Comment: yes

print(X.shape)
(24943, 50, 50, 1)
print(y.shape)
(24943, 50, 50, 1)

Comment: Are you trying to implement some type of Auto Encoder.? If not your `y` should not be of that shape. You have mentioned you want to predict `cats` and `dogs`, so this is a classification problem actually a binary one. So the shape of `y` must be `(24943, 1)`

Comment: BTW, are you sure your `y` is loaded properly. In your codes I can see `pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb"` paranthesis is missing. That line of code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks weird.

try model.summary() and check the dimensions.

Comment: the dimension of activation_2 is (None, 1)

Comment: Append the whole table to you question, please.

Comment: Here is the table

Comment: OK, it is clear now. Your last Dense output is (None, 1) , your y is wrong! 

Most likely ```pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb"` ``` is not open y.pickle and leave the picke_in the old value, file of x.pickle! Don't re-use the python varialbe! Try xfile and yfile instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to classify between two things you'll need your last Dense layer to have 2 neurons.

Maybe you also forgot to one-hot-encode your target vector (`y`). You can do this by:

```py
y = to_categorical(y)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i imported to_categorical from keras.utils it not returning memory error

Comment: Have you also changed the number of outputs of your last Dense layer from 1 to 2?